# Update ActiveRecord without id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-update, identity

In a migration is a table without id column created:

```
create_table :drivers_companies, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :driver
  t.references :company
  t.string :last_sessionid
end
```

When saving a record:

```
dc = DriversCompany.where(company_id: 1, driver_id: 5)
if dc.length>0
  dc[0].last_sessionid = req.sessionID
  dc[0].save!
end
```

I get an error:

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'drivers_companies.' in 'where clause': UPDATE 'drivers_companies' SET 'last_sessionid' = 'bth49sv0outsehcg0ribuiu4h' WHERE 'drivers_companies'.'' IS NULL`

How to update a record in table without ID column?

Comment: This looks like you've got a `has_and_belongs_to_many` when you need a `has_many :through`

Switch it to have an ID and use `has_many :through` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Baloo: Thank you, but my question is not about "how to do the task by all means" but about "There is a feature in Rails. If it exists - it should work. How?"

Comment: The guides say "The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database)."

You want to use it as an independent entity.  You should be using `has_many :through`

The feature in rails does work.  But HABTM isn't designed to have additional attributes on the join table.

Comment: Am I using HABTM feature if I update the binding entity (DriversCompany) directly?

Comment: No, you're trying to use HABTM in the way has many through works.  HABTM doesn't use a model, has many through does.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord needs a primary key to do this. That can be a problem with legacy tables which can not be changed. You can not solve this without changing the table.

Sometimes one can use the "Composite Primary Keys for ActiveRecords" gem to solve it:
https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys